# Picture Perfect

Tags: visual

Most people I know hang paintings and posters on their wall. However my robot friend instead hangs a page of binary on the wall:

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000010001011111011111011111000000001000101000101010101000000000000111110100010101010111110000000010001010001010101010000000000001000101111101010101111100000000000000000000000000000000000011111010101011111011111011111001000001010101000001000000010000111110101010111110111110001000000001010101010000010000000100001111101111101111101111100010000000000000000000000000000000000000010001011111011111011111000000001000101000101010101000000000000111110100010101010111110000000010001010001010101010000000000001000101111101010101111100000000000000000000000000000000000

I have no idea what it means. **Do you?**

Comment: Aw, I bet you DO have an idea what it means...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> HOME SWEET HOME

**Explanation**

> The string is 589=31*19 characters long. Create a 31*19 grid filled when the corresponding digit is 1, and 0 otherwise. The grid then spells HOME SWEET HOME.

Comment: Just to clarify, there are 31 columns and 19 rows.

Answer (score 14):

It says

> Home sweet home
>  The length of this number is 589 = 19*31. If we divide it into 19 lines with 31 symbols each and replace '0' for ' ' we get

this

> ```
>       1   1 11111 11111 11111
>       1   1 1   1 1 1 1 1
>       11111 1   1 1 1 1 11111
>       1   1 1   1 1 1 1 1
>       1   1 11111 1 1 1 11111
>
>     11111 1 1 1 11111 11111 11111
>     1     1 1 1 1     1       1
>     11111 1 1 1 11111 11111   1
>         1 1 1 1 1     1       1
>     11111 11111 11111 11111   1
>
>
>       1   1 11111 11111 11111
>       1   1 1   1 1 1 1 1
>       11111 1   1 1 1 1 11111
>       1   1 1   1 1 1 1 1
>       1   1 11111 1 1 1 11111
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Using the same idea from the other answers, but putting the result into a more visual form, you get this:

> [image]